# Stop animation effects after resuming an activity

Tags: android, animation, onresume

I have added some animations on a view.
After launching an activity, all the animations are starting to animate. After stopping the animation effect I go to another activity that is in the same app. When I come back again to the activity that animation exists in, all animations start to animate again but it is not required.

I need to stop that animation effect after resume is called in an activity. I couldn't find any solutions for that. Any suggestions?

**UPDATED:**
I adding all the animation init and starting in the `onCreate()` method.

**UPDATED:**

Animations are initiating in the `onCreate()` method

```
sparkButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        welcomeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        animationSet.setFillEnabled(true);
        animationSet.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.welcome_slide_right_left);

        animation1.setDuration(700);
        animationSet.addAnimation(animation1);

        final AnimationSet animationSet2 = new AnimationSet(true);
        ScaleAnimation animation2 = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 0.14f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);

        animation2.setDuration(400);
        animation2.setStartOffset(400);
        animationSet2.addAnimation(animation2);

        animationSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                welcomeLayout.setAnimation(animationSet2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        animationSet2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                welcomeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sparkButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sparkButton.playAnimation();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        welcomeLayout.setAnimation(animationSet);
```

I put the source as shown above.
This issue needs to clarify and I will mark the answer as a hack solution. If whether this is an issue of `Animation` object that we didn't handle correctly, That's what I want to resolve

UPDATED:
The button activity to go to another activity

```
        case R.id.spark_button: {
            // network checking code will append here
            // after that calls the activity
            startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
            break;
        }
```

Comment: How do you Naviguate between those Activities ?

Comment: I use the above sparkButton to navigate to another activity and I use `Intent` to navigate over activities

Comment: I don't see the Intent Code, the Code where you launch the Activity from the Button

Comment: Updated thread @UserOne

Comment: I wanted to check that you don't call finish(), my answer should work so, check if savedBundleState is null when you are resuming(from Activity B come back to A), it should'nt

Answer (score 1):

call `clearAnimation()` method for the `View` which is being animate in `onStop()` method of your `activity` not in `onResume` since it also trigger when activity launches for the first time

Comment: I called `clearAnimation()` on `onStop()` method, but still same problem

Comment: just want to confirm are you animating your view in onResume method if so please take that part to onCreate method

Comment: sorry my apology kindly call clearAnimation() method in `onPasue` method 
[see Activity LifeCycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: Still same dude. Any an other suggestion?

Comment: kindly tell me where you are actually adding startAnimation code

Comment: i don't know why its not working i had try it my self its working for my here is the code `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val anim = TranslateAnimation(0f,300f,0f,300f)
        anim.duration = 3000
        anim.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE

        view.animation = anim
        view.animate()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        view.clearAnimation()
        super.onStop()
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You could try as WorkAround to put your start Animation code inside a condition like this in onCreate

```
if(null == savedBundleState) {
 ////Play your Animation
 }
```

Comment: When savedBundleState == null this mean the Activity has just started, So please Post your Code

Answer (score 1):

You can create Boolean and check it always when your activity starts;

```
boolean shouldShowAnimation = true;   

@Override
public void onResume(){       
    super.onResume();
    if(shouldShowAnimation) {
       shouldShowAnimation = false;
       // Your animation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call clearAnimation() on whichever View you called startAnimation().

Hope this helps!